# show songs of an selected album in Listview

Tags: android, eclipse, listview, mediastore

I want to show the songs of an selected album by overriding the currently used `ListView`.

But I don't get it. In this code I show all albums and get their songs.

Maybe you can help me.
Thanks a lot, Vinzenz :)

```
public class Albumsshow extends ListActivity {

public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();


public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.browse);


    ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> albumsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

    AlbumsManager plm = new AlbumsManager();
    // get all songs from sdcard
    this.albumsList = plm.getAlbumList(this);

    // looping through playlist
    for (int i = 0; i < albumsList.size(); i++) {
        // creating new HashMap
        HashMap<String, String> album = albumsList.get(i);

        // adding HashList to ArrayList
        albumsListData.add(album);
    }

    // Adding menuItems to ListView
    ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, albumsListData,
            R.layout.playlist_item, new String[] { "album" }, new int[] {
                    R.id.songTitle });

    setListAdapter(adapter);

    // selecting single ListView item
    final ListView lv = getListView();
    final TextView tv =(TextView)findViewById(R.id.umandern);
    // listening to single listitem click
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                int position, long id) {
            // getting listitem index
            int albumIndex = position;

            String[] column = { MediaStore.Audio.Media.DATA,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME,
                    MediaStore.Audio.Media.MIME_TYPE, };

            String where = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.ALBUM + "=?";

            String whereVal[] = {albumsList.get(albumIndex).get("album") };

            String orderBy = android.provider.MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE;

            Cursor cursor = managedQuery(MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
                    column, where, whereVal, orderBy);

            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    Log.v("music title",
                            cursor.getString(cursor
                                    .getColumnIndex(MediaStore.Audio.Media.DISPLAY_NAME)));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }
    }

    });


}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The code your using is the code i had and it's not overly hard, the only problem you may end up having is actually playing the songs but other than that you can list all albums and the songs like this....

```
  public class AlbumsList extends ListActivity{

public ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> songsList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
 int count;
 Cursor cursor;
 ListView musiclist;
 int songAlbum;
 int position;
 ListView list;
 String songTitle = "";
 String songPath = "";


@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.albums);

    list = (ListView) findViewById(android.R.id.list);


   String[] columns = { BaseColumns._ID,
            AlbumColumns.ALBUM };

        cursor = getContentResolver().query(MediaStore.Audio.Albums.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            columns, null, null, null);

        String[] displayFields = new String[] { AlbumColumns.ALBUM };
        int[] displayViews = new int[] { android.R.id.text1 };
        @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        ListAdapter adapter = (new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, cursor, displayFields,
            displayViews));
          setListAdapter(adapter);


}
public AlbumsList(){

}
    @Override
    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
          if(cursor.moveToPosition(position)){

        ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> songsListData = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();

         // get all songs from sdcard
        this.songsList = this.getPlayList();


        // looping through playlist
        for (int i = 0; i < songsList.size(); i++) {
            // creating new HashMap
            HashMap<String, String> song = songsList.get(i);

            // adding HashList to ArrayList
            songsListData.add(song);
        }
            ListAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(this, songsListData,
                     android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, new String[] { "songTitle", "songPath" }, new int[] {
                     android.R.id.text1});

              setListAdapter(adapter);

                ListView lv = getListView();

                // listening to single listitem click
                lv.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                            int position, long id) {

                        // getting listitem index
                        int songIndex = position;
                        // Starting new intent
                        Intent in = new Intent(AlbumsList.this,
                               MainActivity.class);
                        Log.d("TAG","onItemClick");
                        // Sending songIndex to PlayerActivity
                        in.putExtra("songPath", songIndex);
                        startActivityForResult(in, 99);
                    // Closing PlayListView
                        finish();
                    }
                });
        }
    }

    public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getPlayList(){

         String[] columns = { MediaColumns.DATA,
                  BaseColumns._ID,
                  MediaColumns.TITLE,
                  MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, };

              String where = AudioColumns.ALBUM
                  + "=?";

              String whereVal[] = { cursor.getString(cursor
                  .getColumnIndex(AlbumColumns.ALBUM))};

              String orderBy = MediaColumns.TITLE;



              cursor = this.getContentResolver().query(
                  MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,columns,
                  where, whereVal, orderBy);

          if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {

        songTitle = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.TITLE));
        songPath = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaColumns.DATA));


          HashMap<String, String> song = new HashMap<String, String>();


         song.put("songTitle", songTitle);
         song.put("songPath", songPath);
         songsList.add(song);

                } while (cursor.moveToNext());

          }
          cursor.close();
        return songsList;

    }
```